# Не могу разобраться с интерфейсом в TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Интерфейс:

```
export interface Interpreter {
  getStep(): number;
  run(text: string): any;
}
```

Класс имплементирующий интерфейс:

```
import { Interpreter } from '../interpreter.interface';

export class FalseInterpreter implements Interpreter {
  getStep(): number {
    return 0;
  }

  run(code: string): string {
    return '123';
  }
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Property 'getStep' is missing in type 'typeof FalseInterpreter'

В чем, собственно, проблема?

П.С. Вот так я все это использую:

```
import { Languange } from './languange';

import { FalseTasks } from './tasks/false/tasks';
import { FalseInterpreter } from './interpreters/false/interpreter';

var languanges: Languange[] = [
  { name: 'FALSE', tasks: FalseTasks, interpreter: FalseInterpreter }
];
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос **FalseIntrepreter**

Comment: Извиняюсь, это опечатка. Поправил.

Comment: возможно у Вас несколько Interpreter в одном файле. Возможно tsc не понимает что в пути '../interpreter.interface' .interface это не расширение файла. Не могу не заметить и не указать на бредовую идею называть классы и файлы классов по разному, возможно сейчас Вам это и удобно но в будущем эта привычка может сыграть дурную шутку и Вам придется ПОТОМ учится делать правильно. На мой взгляд учше сразу правильно писать. Что самое интересно, если бы Вы писали правильно, то мои предположения были бы не актуальны. А если я угадал причину, то не было бы и вопроса.

Comment: @OlmerDale - путь здесь вообще ни при чем.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
var languanges: Languange[] = [
  { name: 'FALSE', tasks: FalseTasks, interpreter: new FalseInterpreter() },
];
```